# Formatting currency and percentage in input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, currency, percentage

I was only able to insert a "$" sign in a3.  I also need to insert the "$" sign for a1 but when I insert format for a1 field in like this

$('#a3').val(format($('#a1').val(format) * $('#a2').val()));

I get an error.  What is the best way to do this?

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>You</td>
            <td class="light-gray">Example</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="20%">a1
                <input type="textbox" class="form-control" id="a1" name="a1" />
            </td>
            <td width="20%" class="light-gray">$30,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a2
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a2" name="a2" />
            </td>
            <td class="light-gray">90%</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>a3
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="a3" name="a3" data-cell="a3" />
            </td>
            <td class="light-gray">$27,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="heading">
            <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
        </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

  var format = function (num) {
      var str = num.toString().replace("$", ""),
          parts = false,
          output = [],
          i = 1,
          formatted = null;
      if (str.indexOf(".") > 0) {
          parts = str.split(".");
          str = parts[0];
      }
      str = str.split("").reverse();
      for (var j = 0, len = str.length; j < len; j++) {
          if (str[j] != ",") {
              output.push(str[j]);
              if (i % 3 == 0 && j < (len - 1)) {
                  output.push(",");
              }
              i++;
          }
      }
      formatted = output.reverse().join("");
      return ("$" + formatted + ((parts) ? "." + parts[1].substr(0, 2) : ""));
  };
  $("#a1,#a2").keyup(function (e) {
      $('#a3').val(format($('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val()));
  });
```

});

[JSFiddle Examples](https://jsfiddle.net/hn669das/13/)

Comment: Please include [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) in the question. If you're not interested in attempting to solve your own problem, I recommend hiring a programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you assume the values inside the inputs to be numbers. Since you format those with non-digit-characters they are not (and can not be casted to a number).

```
$('#a1').val() * $('#a2').val()
```

**Since the values you are multiplying are no numbers an error is thrown.**

To be able to multiply those strings (or to be exact the value they are representing) you need to unformat your strings before you can cast those to numbers and do your calculation!
You'll find an working example at https://jsfiddle.net/hn669das/18/.

**By the way:** Better use the change-event for formatting instead of the keyUp-event since the user won't be able to write into the input undisturbed when the input is manipulated while the user intends to write to it. The change-event will trigger when the input looses its focus and so won't disturb the user.

I hope that helps you!

Comment: Yes very helpful. Thank you very much.  In addition, I'm attempting to add select options for the drop down, I was wondering why the option "selected" is not display in the option box any suggestions? see this behaviors
<select class="form-control" id="a2" name="a2">
                    <option value=".1">10%</option>
                    <option value=".9">90%</option>
                </select>

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hn669das/20/)

Comment: when you want to set the value of a select you need to set it to the value of one of its options... so you can set it concrete to '.1' or '.9' and this will work. You set the value of the select to a value which none of the options has (e.g. '90%').In result of that no option gets selected which has the visual effect of an empty select. To achieve what you want you dont need that percentage-formatter since you do the formatting manually by giving the formatted label for the option with unformatted value. Your code without the percentage-formatting works for me https://jsfiddle.net/hn669das/24/

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful.